# Paint.getTextWidths. What is advance width?

Tags: android, text, measurement

What is advance width?

The term comes up in the android class `Paint`, specifically the function `getTextWidths()`.
The documentation states *“Return the advance widths for the characters in the string”*.

what is the “advance widths?”

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Advance Width** is a metrics term related to fonts/typography. There are some Q&A's here on SO that cover it, but the short definition is more or less:

> The advance width is the distance between the glyph's initial pen
>   position and the next glyph's initial pen position.

A visualization usually makes things easier to understand, so have a look at the image below.

[image]

*Image courtesy of freetype.org.*

Similar to the advance width, there is also a less frequently used *advance height*:

[image]

*Image courtesy of freetype.org.*

[Freetype's article on glyps metrics](http://www.freetype.org/freetype2/docs/glyphs/glyphs-3.html) goes more in depth about the various metrics. Might be worth a read if you're interested.

Note: I'm in no way affiliated with Freetype.org. I just happen to find their documentation on this matter useful.