# How to create Room name Text inside the room element?

Tags: autodesk-forge

Is there any way to create room name text inside the room element in forge viewer?

I have room elements in the forge viewer as per the below image.
So, I can read a room name from element properties. Then, I want to create room name text in forge viewer. May I have the solution?

[image: Rooms at forge viewer]

Thanks In advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update 2021-06-29**

Added some conditions to avoid invalid data input.

```js
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Copyright (c) Autodesk, Inc. All rights reserved
// Written by Forge Partner Development
//
// Permission to use, copy, modify, and distribute this software in
// object code form for any purpose and without fee is hereby granted,
// provided that the above copyright notice appears in all copies and
// that both that copyright notice and the limited warranty and
// restricted rights notice below appear in all supporting
// documentation.
//
// AUTODESK PROVIDES THIS PROGRAM 'AS IS' AND WITH ALL FAULTS.
// AUTODESK SPECIFICALLY DISCLAIMS ANY IMPLIED WARRANTY OF
// MERCHANTABILITY OR FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR USE.  AUTODESK, INC.
// DOES NOT WARRANT THAT THE OPERATION OF THE PROGRAM WILL BE
// UNINTERRUPTED OR ERROR FREE.
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61262544
class TextMeasurer {
    constructor() {
        const SVG_NS = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg';

        this.svg = document.createElementNS(SVG_NS, 'svg');

        this.svg.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        this.svg.setAttribute('xmlns', SVG_NS)
        this.svg.setAttribute('width', 0);
        this.svg.setAttribute('height', 0);

        this.svgtext = document.createElementNS(SVG_NS, 'text');
        this.svg.appendChild(this.svgtext);
        this.svgtext.setAttribute('x', 0);
        this.svgtext.setAttribute('y', 0);

        document.querySelector('body').appendChild(this.svg);
    }

    /**
     * Measure a single line of text, including the bounding box, inner size and lead and trail X
     * @param {string} text Single line of text
     * @param {string} fontFamily Name of font family
     * @param {string} fontSize Font size including units
     */
    measureText(text, fontFamily, fontSize) {
        this.svgtext.setAttribute('font-family', fontFamily);
        this.svgtext.setAttribute('font-size', fontSize);
        this.svgtext.textContent = text;

        let bbox = this.svgtext.getBBox();
        let textLength = this.svgtext.getComputedTextLength();

        // measure the overflow before and after the line caused by font side bearing
        // Rendering should start at X + leadX to have the edge of the text appear at X
        // when rendering left-aligned left-to-right
        let baseX = parseInt(this.svgtext.getAttribute('x'));
        let overflow = bbox.width - textLength;
        let leadX = Math.abs(baseX - bbox.x);
        let trailX = overflow - leadX;

        document.querySelector('body').removeChild(this.svg);

        return {
            bbWidth: bbox.width,
            textLength: textLength,
            leadX: leadX,
            trailX: trailX,
            bbHeight: bbox.height
        };
    }
}

class AecRoomTagsExtension extends Autodesk.Viewing.Extension {
    constructor(viewer, options) {
        super(viewer, options);

        this.modelBuilder = null;
        this.idPrefix = 100;
    }

    async load() {
        const modelBuilderExt = await this.viewer.loadExtension('Autodesk.Viewing.SceneBuilder');
        const modelBuilder = await modelBuilderExt.addNewModel({
            conserveMemory: false,
            modelNameOverride: 'Room Tags'
        });

        this.modelBuilder = modelBuilder;

        if (!this.viewer.isLoadDone()) {
            this.viewer.addEventListener(
                Autodesk.Viewing.GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT,
                () => this.createRoomTags(),
                { once: true }
            );
        } else {
            this.createRoomTags();
        }

        return true;
    }

    unload() {
        this.viewer.impl.unloadModel(this.modelBuilder.model);
        return true;
    }

    pxToMm(val) {
        return val / 3.7795275591;
    }

    mmToFt(val) {
        return val / 304.8;
    }

    createLabel(params) {
        const text = params.text;

        const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        ctx.fillStyle = 'yellow';
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        const fontSize = params.fontSize || 512;
        const fontName = 'serif';
        let offset = 2;
        //Usage:
        let m = new TextMeasurer();
        let textDimensions = m.measureText(text, fontName, `${fontSize}px`);
        canvas.height = textDimensions.bbHeight - (fontSize / 32 + 2) * offset;
        canvas.width = textDimensions.bbWidth + offset + 3 * offset;

        ctx.textBaseline = 'top';
        ctx.fillStyle = '#000';
        ctx.textAlign = 'left';
        ctx.font = `${fontSize}px ${fontName}`;
        ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, textDimensions.bbWidth + offset * 2, canvas.height);
        ctx.fillStyle = '#000';
        ctx.fillText(text, offset, offset + (fontSize / 32 + 3) * offset);

        ctx.strokeRect(0, 0, textDimensions.bbWidth + offset * 2, canvas.height);
        const labelBlobUrl = canvas.toDataURL();

        //console.log(labelBlobUrl);

        const image = new Image();
        const texture = new THREE.Texture();

        texture.image = image;
        image.src = labelBlobUrl;
        image.onload = function () {
            texture.needsUpdate = true;
        };

        const labelDbId = this.idPrefix++;
        const matName = `label-mat-${labelDbId}`;
        const material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ map: texture, side: THREE.DoubleSide, opacity: 0.8, transparent: true });
        material.map.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
        this.modelBuilder.addMaterial(matName, material);
        const labelMat = this.modelBuilder.findMaterial(matName);

        const planeWidth = this.mmToFt(this.pxToMm(canvas.width));
        const planeHeight = this.mmToFt(this.pxToMm(canvas.height));

        let planeGeo = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(planeWidth, planeHeight);
        let plane = new THREE.Mesh(planeGeo, labelMat);

        plane.matrix = new THREE.Matrix4().compose(
            params.position,
            new THREE.Quaternion(0, 0, 0, 1),
            new THREE.Vector3(1, 1, 1)
        );
        plane.dbId = labelDbId;
        this.modelBuilder.addMesh(plane);
    }

    async createRoomTags() {
        const getRoomDbIdsAsync = () => {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                this.viewer.search(
                    'Revit Rooms',
                    (dbIds) => resolve(dbIds),
                    (error) => reject(error),
                    ['Category'],
                    { searchHidden: true }
                );
            });
        };

        const getPropertiesAsync = (dbId, model) => {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                model.getProperties2(
                    dbId,
                    (result) => resolve(result),
                    (error) => reject(error)
                );
            });
        };

        const getBoxAsync = (dbId, model) => {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                const tree = model.getInstanceTree();
                const frags = model.getFragmentList();

                let bounds = new THREE.Box3();
                tree.enumNodeFragments(dbId, function (fragId) {
                    let box = new THREE.Box3();
                    frags.getWorldBounds(fragId, box);
                    bounds.union(box);
                }, true);
                return resolve(bounds);
            });
        };

        const getRoomNameAsync = async (dbId, model) => {
            const tree = model.getInstanceTree();
            let name = tree.getNodeName(dbId);
            if (!name) {
                const props = await getPropertiesAsync(dbId, model);
                name = props?.name;
            }
            return name;
        };

        try {
            let roomDbIds = await getRoomDbIdsAsync();
            if (!roomDbIds || roomDbIds.length <= 0) {
                throw new Error('No Rooms found in current model');
            }

            const model = this.viewer.model;
            const currentViewableId = this.viewer.model?.getDocumentNode().data.viewableID;
            const masterViews = this.viewer.model?.getDocumentNode().getMasterViews();
            const masterViewIds = masterViews?.map(v => v.data.viewableID);

            if (!masterViewIds.includes(currentViewableId)) {
                throw new Error('Current view does not contain any Rooms');
            }

            for (let i = 0; i < roomDbIds.length; i++) {
                const dbId = roomDbIds[i];

                const name = await getRoomNameAsync(dbId, model);
                if (!name) {
                    console.warn(`[AecRoomTagsExtension]: ${dbId} Room \`${name}\` doesn't have valid name`);
                    continue;
                }

                const roomProps = await getPropertiesAsync(dbId, model);
                const possibleViewableIds = roomProps.properties.filter(prop => prop.attributeName === 'viewable_in').map(prop => prop.displayValue);
                if (!possibleViewableIds.includes(currentViewableId)) {
                    console.warn(`[AecRoomTagsExtension]: ${dbId} Room \`${name}\` is not visible in current view \`${currentViewableId}\``);
                    continue;
                }

                const box = await getBoxAsync(dbId, model);
                if (!box) {
                    console.warn(`[AecRoomTagsExtension]: ${dbId} Room \`${name}\` has an invalid bounding box`);
                    continue;
                }

                const center = box.center();
                if (isNaN(center.x) || isNaN(center.y) || isNaN(center.z)) {
                    console.warn(`[AecRoomTagsExtension]: ${dbId} Room \`${name}\` has an invalid bounding box`);
                    continue;
                }

                //console.log(i, dbId, name, box, center);

                const pos = new THREE.Vector3(
                    center.x,
                    center.y,
                    box.min.z + this.mmToFt(10)
                );

                this.createLabel({
                    text: name.replace(/ *\[[^)]*\] */g, ""),
                    position: pos,
                    fontSize: 512 // in pixel
                });
            }

            // uncomment to prevent selection on tags
            // const dbIds = this.modelBuilder.model.getFragmentList().fragments.fragId2dbId;
            // const model = this.modelBuilder.model;
            // this.viewer.lockSelection(dbIds, true, model);
        } catch (ex) {
            console.warn(`[AecRoomTagsExtension]: ${ex}`);
        }
    }
}

Autodesk.Viewing.theExtensionManager.registerExtension('Autodesk.ADN.AecRoomTagsExtension', AecRoomTagsExtension);
```

=============================

It's similar to the Gird solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68129012/7745569

Not perfect, but it works. You may need to adjust the tag placement point (position) based on your model. Currently, tags are placed on the center of the bottom face of the Room bounding box.

```js
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Copyright (c) Autodesk, Inc. All rights reserved
// Written by Forge Partner Development
//
// Permission to use, copy, modify, and distribute this software in
// object code form for any purpose and without fee is hereby granted,
// provided that the above copyright notice appears in all copies and
// that both that copyright notice and the limited warranty and
// restricted rights notice below appear in all supporting
// documentation.
//
// AUTODESK PROVIDES THIS PROGRAM 'AS IS' AND WITH ALL FAULTS.
// AUTODESK SPECIFICALLY DISCLAIMS ANY IMPLIED WARRANTY OF
// MERCHANTABILITY OR FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR USE.  AUTODESK, INC.
// DOES NOT WARRANT THAT THE OPERATION OF THE PROGRAM WILL BE
// UNINTERRUPTED OR ERROR FREE.
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61262544
class TextMeasurer {
    constructor() {
        const SVG_NS = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg';

        this.svg = document.createElementNS(SVG_NS, 'svg');

        this.svg.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        this.svg.setAttribute('xmlns', SVG_NS)
        this.svg.setAttribute('width', 0);
        this.svg.setAttribute('height', 0);

        this.svgtext = document.createElementNS(SVG_NS, 'text');
        this.svg.appendChild(this.svgtext);
        this.svgtext.setAttribute('x', 0);
        this.svgtext.setAttribute('y', 0);

        document.querySelector('body').appendChild(this.svg);
    }

    /**
     * Measure a single line of text, including the bounding box, inner size and lead and trail X
     * @param {string} text Single line of text
     * @param {string} fontFamily Name of font family
     * @param {string} fontSize Font size including units
     */
    measureText(text, fontFamily, fontSize) {
        this.svgtext.setAttribute('font-family', fontFamily);
        this.svgtext.setAttribute('font-size', fontSize);
        this.svgtext.textContent = text;

        let bbox = this.svgtext.getBBox();
        let textLength = this.svgtext.getComputedTextLength();

        // measure the overflow before and after the line caused by font side bearing
        // Rendering should start at X + leadX to have the edge of the text appear at X
        // when rendering left-aligned left-to-right
        let baseX = parseInt(this.svgtext.getAttribute('x'));
        let overflow = bbox.width - textLength;
        let leadX = Math.abs(baseX - bbox.x);
        let trailX = overflow - leadX;

        document.querySelector('body').removeChild(this.svg);

        return {
            bbWidth: bbox.width,
            textLength: textLength,
            leadX: leadX,
            trailX: trailX,
            bbHeight: bbox.height
        };
    }
}

class AecRoomTagsExtension extends Autodesk.Viewing.Extension {
    constructor(viewer, options) {
        super(viewer, options);

        this.modelBuilder = null;
        this.idPrefix = 100;
    }

    async load() {
        const modelBuilderExt = await this.viewer.loadExtension('Autodesk.Viewing.SceneBuilder');
        const modelBuilder = await modelBuilderExt.addNewModel({
            conserveMemory: false,
            modelNameOverride: 'Room Tags'
        });

        this.modelBuilder = modelBuilder;

        if (!this.viewer.isLoadDone()) {
            this.viewer.addEventListener(
                Autodesk.Viewing.GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT,
                () => this.createRoomTags(),
                { once: true }
            );
        } else {
            this.createRoomTags();
        }

        return true;
    }

    unload() {
        this.viewer.impl.unloadModel(this.modelBuilder.model);
        return true;
    }

    pxToMm(val) {
        return val / 3.7795275591;
    }

    mmToFt(val) {
        return val / 304.8;
    }

    createLabel(params) {
        const text = params.text;

        const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        ctx.fillStyle = 'yellow';
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        const fontSize = params.fontSize || 512;
        const fontName = 'serif';
        let offset = 2;
        //Usage:
        let m = new TextMeasurer();
        let textDimensions = m.measureText(text, fontName, `${fontSize}px`);
        canvas.height = textDimensions.bbHeight  - (fontSize / 32 + 2) * offset;
        canvas.width = textDimensions.bbWidth + offset + 3 * offset;

        ctx.textBaseline = 'top';
        ctx.fillStyle = '#000';
        ctx.textAlign = 'left';
        ctx.font = `${fontSize}px ${fontName}`;
        ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, textDimensions.bbWidth + offset * 2, canvas.height);
        ctx.fillStyle = '#000';
        ctx.fillText(text, offset, offset + (fontSize / 32 + 3) * offset);

        ctx.strokeRect(0, 0, textDimensions.bbWidth + offset * 2, canvas.height);
        const labelBlobUrl = canvas.toDataURL();

        //console.log(labelBlobUrl);

        const image = new Image();
        const texture = new THREE.Texture();

        texture.image = image;
        image.src = labelBlobUrl;
        image.onload = function () {
            texture.needsUpdate = true;
        };

        const planeWidth = this.mmToFt(this.pxToMm(canvas.width));
        const planeHeight = this.mmToFt(this.pxToMm(canvas.height));

        let planeGeo = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(planeWidth, planeHeight);
        let plane = new THREE.Mesh(planeGeo, new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ map: texture, side: THREE.DoubleSide, opacity: 0.8, transparent: true }));

        plane.matrix = new THREE.Matrix4().compose(
            params.position,
            new THREE.Quaternion(0, 0, 0, 1),
            new THREE.Vector3(1, 1, 1)
        );
        plane.dbId = this.idPrefix++;
        this.modelBuilder.addMesh(plane);
    }

    async createRoomTags() {
        const getRoomDbIdsAsync = () => {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                this.viewer.search(
                    'Revit Rooms',
                    (dbIds) => resolve(dbIds),
                    (error) => reject(error),
                    ['Category'],
                    { searchHidden: true }
                );
            });
        };

        const getPropertiesAsync = (dbId, model) => {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                model.getProperties2(
                    dbId,
                    (result) => resolve(result),
                    (error) => reject(error)
                );
            });
        };

        const getBoxAsync = (dbId, model) => {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                const tree = model.getInstanceTree();
                const frags = model.getFragmentList();
                tree.enumNodeFragments(dbId, function (fragId) {
                    let bounds = new THREE.Box3();
                    frags.getWorldBounds(fragId, bounds);
                    return resolve(bounds);
                }, true);
            });
        };

        const getRoomName = (dbId, model) => {
            const tree = model.getInstanceTree();
            return tree.getNodeName(dbId);
        };

        try {
            const roomDbIds = await getRoomDbIdsAsync();
            if (!roomDbIds || roomDbIds.length <= 0) {
                throw new Error('No Rooms found in current model');
            }

            const model = this.viewer.model;
            const currentViewableId = this.viewer.model?.getDocumentNode().data.viewableID;
            const firstRoomProps = await getPropertiesAsync(roomDbIds[0], this.viewer.model);
            const possibleViewableIds = firstRoomProps.properties.filter(prop => prop.attributeName === 'viewable_in').map(prop => prop.displayValue);
            const masterViews = this.viewer.model?.getDocumentNode().getMasterViews();
            const masterViewIds = masterViews?.map(v => v.data.viewableID);

            if (!masterViewIds.includes(currentViewableId) || !possibleViewableIds.includes(currentViewableId)) {
                throw new Error('Current view does not contain any Rooms');
            }

            for (let i = roomDbIds.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                const dbId = roomDbIds[i];
                const box = await getBoxAsync(dbId, model);
                const name = getRoomName(dbId, model);
                const center = box.center();
                const pos = new THREE.Vector3(
                    center.x,
                    center.y,
                    box.min.z + this.mmToFt(10)
                );

                this.createLabel({
                    text: name.replace(/ *\[[^)]*\] */g, ""),
                    position: pos,
                    fontSize: 512 // in pixel
                });
            }

            // uncomment to prevent selection on tags
            // const dbIds = this.modelBuilder.model.getFragmentList().fragments.fragId2dbId;
            // const model = this.modelBuilder.model;
            // this.viewer.lockSelection(dbIds, true, model);
        } catch (ex) {
            console.warn(`[AecRoomTagsExtension]: ${ex}`);
        }
    }
}

Autodesk.Viewing.theExtensionManager.registerExtension('Autodesk.ADN.AecRoomTagsExtension', AecRoomTagsExtension);
```

Here are the dmeo snapshots:

[image]

[image]